# Migrating from Exist DB 2.1 to 5.x - Missing modules/functions

Tags: xquery, exist-db

I'm in the process of migrating an Exist DB app based on 2.1 to 5.x and am having trouble finding replacements for a couple of apparently deprecated / moved functions.  They are:

- context:get-attribute
- context:set-attribute
- text:groups-regex

Any guidance on replacements or alternative approaches would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Context Module was removed in eXist-db 5.0.0 as its only purpose was to allow mutable variable storage within a single running XQuery. This is really just bad-practice, instead your XQuery should be refactored to pass variables around.

Instead of text:groups-regex, you probably want fn:analyze-string.